# Installing Distribute in Windows

Tags: python, distribute

I am following [these](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/) instructions to install Distribute in Windows 7, but when I run the script to install I get the following error message:

```
Extracting in c:\users\michae~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpuvkx38
Now working in c:\users\michae~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpuvkx38\distribute-0.6.45
Installing Distribute
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Downloads\distribute_setup.py", line 556, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
SystemExit: 2
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Install from these [Windows packagings](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute) instead.

Comment: I ran the windows installer, which seemed to work, but the command "easy_install pip" still does not work.

Comment: Define 'does not work'; is `Scripts` on your path.

Comment: Does not work is defined as getting the following error message: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" Define "on your path"

Comment: Is there a more complete traceback for that error?

Comment: That is the entire error message.

Comment: That is unfortunate and unhelpful; running python, without any command line switches or arguments works?